# Passing parent data to child screen (drawer navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I am trying to pass the state data from `App.js` to my drawer screen which is located at a different file but the props unable to retrieve the data.

**App.js**

```js
render() {
  return (
    <GalioProvider theme={argonTheme}>
      <Block flex>
      <Screens user={this.state.user} />
      </Block>
    </GalioProvider>
  );
}
```

**Screen.js**

```js
const AppStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack,
      navigationOptions: (navOpt) => ({
        drawerLabel: ({ focused }) => (
          <DrawerItem focused={focused} title="Home" />
        ),
      }),
    },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: (props) => {
      console.log(props.user);
      return (
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
        ></View>
      );
    },
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStack);
export default AppContainer;
```

The `console.log(props.user)` line is returning `undefined`